# how to create a extension system for for uwp with c#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Could you please tell me how to create a extension system or additional features packs from third party developers for an app.
Extension should be downloaded from the internet and they should be able to access features from my app. I tried using reflection to find namespaces with a specific class like "ExtensionInitialise" to find new extensions but uwp sadly doesn't support assembly load or something like that( I'm kind of a beginner to advanced programming). So my question is how do I create an app that can download extensions from its own store and those extensions should be able to access some objects from the app itself (static classes also if possible). Elaborate answers are preferred or just point me to a article. Thanks guys.

Comment: The magic search word is [`AppExtension`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B808).

Comment: Thanks bro, that was hard very to find